# Select preceeding checkbox if the following checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to check box K and F is selected if Check box D is checked and other checkbox to be unchecked, Similarly, if the check box I is selected the preceding chekbox of I to be selected and the following to be unchecked.
My html code is:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" class= "knitting" name="knitting[]" value="1">K</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class= "fmending" name="fmending[]" value="1">F</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class= "dyeing" name="dyeing[]" value="1">D</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class = "firon" name="firon[]" value="1">Y</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class= "linking" name="linking[]" value="1">L</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="smending" name="smending[]" value="1">S</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="siron" name="siron[]" value="1">I</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="packing" name="packing[]" value="1">P</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="data" name="data[]" value="1">D</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="chalan" name="chalan[]" value="1">C</td>
```

And what I have done for that is :

```
$(".dyeing").click(function () {
    $(".knitting").prop("checked", true);
    $(".fmending").prop("checked", true);
    $(".firon").prop("checked", false);
    $(".linking").prop("checked", false);
    $(".smending").prop("checked", false);
    $(".siron").prop("checked", false);
    $(".packing").prop("checked", false);
    $(".data").prop("checked", false);
    $(".chalan").prop("checked", false);
});
```

This looks messy, is there another cool process???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with **[:lt()](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)** and **[:gt()](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)** selectors:

```
$(":checkbox").on('change',function () {
   var idx=$(this).index();
   $(":checkbox:lt("+idx+")").prop('checked',true);
   $(":checkbox:gt("+idx+")").prop('checked',false);             
});
```

Check the **below snippet**

```js
var idx = 0;
var chk = $('table tr :checkbox');
$("table tr :checkbox").on('change', function() {
  var index = chk.index($(this));
  if (idx < index) {
    idx = index;
    $("table tr :checkbox:lt(" + idx + ")").prop('checked', true);
    $(":checkbox:gt(" + idx + ")").prop('checked', false);
  } else if (idx == index && !$(this).prop('checked')) {

    $(":checkbox").prop('checked', false);
  } else {
    idx = chk.index($(this));
    $(":checkbox:lt(" + idx + ")").prop('checked', true);
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
    $(":checkbox:gt(" + idx + ")").prop('checked', false);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="knitting" name="knitting[]" value="1">K</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="fmending" name="fmending[]" value="1">F</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="dyeing" name="dyeing[]" value="1">D</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="firon" name="firon[]" value="1">Y</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="linking" name="linking[]" value="1">L</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="smending" name="smending[]" value="1">S</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="siron" name="siron[]" value="1">I</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="packing" name="packing[]" value="1">P</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="data" name="data[]" value="1">D</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chalan" name="chalan[]" value="1">C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How can i implement in table?

Comment: @Xravn How your table looks like? you can use `$('table tr :checkbox') `selector instead of `$(' :checkbox')`, . also I don't know your desired behavior when some checkbox got unchecked, so I made a little adjustment for that, check this link: https://jsfiddle.net/5aL55wp9/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can do,

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
  if (this.checked)
    $("td:lt(" + $(this).closest("td").index() + ") input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/216/)

Comment: but if again unchecked on I check box the following is not unchecked

Comment: ya just looked up but not working 
for example please check on checkbox C and uncheck Y
I need to uncheck all the checkbox after Y

Comment: NO  but the answer give by itsgoingdown is woking 
btw thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: This solution is useful for the case where you do not want to check/uncheck only consecutive checkboxes, but any checkbox can be checked/unchecked based on which checkbox is clicked.

Yes, you can add multiple classes e.g. dyeingfalse, knittingtrue etc. to the checkboxes. Also, give each checkbox a data attribute e.g. data-name="dyeing".

Now,

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function(){
  if( $(this).is(":checked") )
  {
    var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
    $("input."+name+"false").prop("checked", false);
    $("input."+name+"true").prop("checked", true);
  }//if
});//click handler
```